# Nulls in InnoDBs clustered index?

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb, clustered-index

Using InnoDB in MySQL, I want to speed up selects by utilizing the clustered index better, thus including more frequently used columns in the primary key.

But some frequent columns used are allowed to be null (and some times are). Is there any way to include these in the clustered index (and allow them to be null)?

If not, are there some workarounds or is there some other way to do something similar?

Comment: Do you really think it is smart to expand the primary index? I don't know your Db structure, or how you run your queries, but from the get-go it sounds like a bad idea to tamper with the primary index. You can always add a compiled (unique) index on multiple fields, starting with the primary field. Regarding your NULL situation, would it be an option to change the NULL values into an empty string value ('')?

Comment: I'm doing a select with about 7 joins on simple tables. When experimenting I added a frequently used column to PK (the column is just used to get it's data, not to join on or condition on), then the query time decreased from ~0.24s to ~0.11s. I'm hoping for some (if not similar) improvements for the other tables (as they have the same form and are used similarly). The only problem is that the data can be NULL. If these were string values I guess empty string would work, but for number values I can't use 0 since it's one of the valid values anyway.

Comment: Well, for any type of optimization (adding proper indexes is optimizing), normalizing your data fields will make a big difference. Not only will this make things easier for the scripts that are processing the field data, the index itself will become simpler (typically lowering the cardinality). As for your PRIMARY, this should be a row id (the simpler/ smaller, the better). Any type of joining should happen over those numbers. When you added a non-joining column to the PRIMARY, it sped up because it narrowed down the rows to examine based on your 'WHERE' clause.

Comment: The reason why it sped up like this is because joined indexes limit the scope of the next index. For example, if you have two seperate indexes on clmnA and clmnB and a query with '...WHERE clmnA='3' AND clmn2='4'...', it will first use the first index to quickly find clmnA values that match and then do the same for clmnB. With a joined index (INDEX (clmnA,clmnB)), it will find matches for clmnA and then search a <i>selection</i> of rows for a match on clmnB (hence the performance boost). Properly indexing for JOINS however, typically yields better results.

Comment: Now, I have no clue what your Db/ table/ index structure looks like, so it is a little hard for me to say what will actually help in your case. It would help if you give us a table structures, a list of indexes per table, a sample query, and the results of an EXPLAIN of that same query. Sorry for these long comments....but I rather wanted to be clear than short x)

Comment: @Battle_707, thanks for your input, I could post the table structure and some queries, but those are rather large. Altho I could show a bit smaller examples. You are right about normalizing, that way I could avoid these null problems all together. But after testing it seems that doing the same thing (adding the selected data to PK) for other tables joined on in the same query had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalizing the table to exclude the nullable field would work in this case (as commented by Battle_707).